# Copy constructor doesn't work

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have some code that creates an array of documents.  Each document object has an array of document-wide values, and an array of individual files (called lines because each is a line in the source file I'm reading from) that together have all the document data.  When I attempt to add a document object to the array, it is calling my copy constructor below:

```
CMyDocument::CMyDocument(CMyDocument& cSourceDoc)
{
    m_lpastrFields = new CStringArray;
    m_lpacLines = new CArray<CMyLine, CMyLine>;
    int nCount;
    int nSize;
    nSize = static_cast<int>(cSourceDoc.GetFields()->GetSize());
    for (nCount = 0; nCount < nSize; nCount++)
    {
        m_lpastrFields->Add(cSourceDoc.GetFields()->GetAt(nCount));
    }
    nSize = static_cast<int>(cSourceDoc.GetLines()->GetSize());
    for (nCount = 0; nCount < nSize; nCount++)
    {
        m_lpacLines->Add(cSourceDoc.GetLines()->GetAt(nCount));
    }
    m_strDocDate = cSourceDoc.GetDocDate();
    m_nDocID = cSourceDoc.GetDocID();
    m_strDocType = cSourceDoc.GetDocType();
}
```

The problem is, when I try to access the documents by pulling them from the document array later, the two arrays I've copied above are empty. The seem to be initialized and have memory addresses, but they contain no data.  The member variables are populated though. I'm not sure if I'm doing the copying incorrectly or if the problem is elsewhere.

**EDIT:** The regular constructor looks like this:

```
CMyDocument::CMyDocument()
{
    m_lpastrFields = new CStringArray;
}
```

I don't new the `m_lpacLines` object in this case because it is passed into the MyDocument object through a function called InitDocument.  I may as well include that here. (Some unnecessary details, like the way I parse the `strLine` variable to extract all the values, were trimmed for brevity's sake.

```
void CMyDocument::InitDocument(CMyColumns* lpcColumns, CString strLine, CArray<CMyLine, CMyLine>* lpacLines)
{
    CString strValue;
    CString strComma = ",";
    int     nPos = 0;

    m_lpacLines = lpacLines;

    while (-1 != nPos)
    {
        strValue = strLine.Tokenize(strComma, nPos);
        m_lpastrFields->Add(strValue);
    }
    m_strDocDate = m_lpastrFields->GetAt(lpcColumns->GetDocDateIndex());
    CString strDocID = m_lpastrFields->GetAt(lpcColumns->GetDocIDIndex());
    m_nDocID = atoi(strDocID);
    m_strDocType = m_lpastrFields->GetAt(lpcColumns->GetDocTypeIndex());
}
```

And to be clear, I am `new`ing the lpacLines object outside of the `InitDocument` function every time I loop through.  I've already debugged this code though and everything is being assigned correctly here.

**SECOND EDIT:** In trying to convert these all the non-pointer member variables, I am now coming up against error C2248:'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'.  Upon reflection, problems like this may have been what pushed me towards using pointers in the first place.

**THIRD EDIT:** Here is the class declaration:

```
class CMyDocument
{
    public:
        CMyDocument();
        ~CMyDocument();
        CMyDocument(CMyDocument& cSourceDoc);
        void    InitDocument(CMyColumns* lpcColumns, CString strLine, CArray<CMyLine, CMyLine>* lpacLines);
        inline  CString GetDocDate(void) {return(m_strDocDate);};
        inline  int     GetDocID(void) {return(m_nDocID);};
        inline  CString GetDocType(void) {return(m_strDocType);};

        inline  CStringArray*   GetFields(void) {return(m_lpastrFields);};
        inline  CArray<CMyLine, CMyLine>*   GetLines(void) {return m_lpacLines;};
    private:
        CArray<CMyLine, CMyLine>*   m_lpacLines;
        CStringArray*   m_lpastrFields;

        CString             m_strDocDate;
        int                 m_nDocID;
        CString             m_strDocType;
};
```

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but why do you allocate them with `new`? You could just have two member variables `CStringArray m_fields` and `CArray<CMyLine, CMyLine> m_lines` and let the implicitly-generated copy constructors do the work.

Comment: I've vacillated back and forth on that, but I made them pointers because I use them in a few different places and it seems easier to keep a single copy with multiple pointers because I had some concerns about using up all my memory, as the total number of lines could potentially top one million, with each line object have an array of 70 values.  But perhaps it wouldn't matter, since the duplicates wouldn't be around for long and not all at once.

Comment: It looks like *the problem is elsewhere*.  Step through that copy constructor with a debugger to verify.

Comment: Also, since you seem to work with pointers, make sure you're not trying to invoke a member function through a pointer that happens to be null

Comment: @DrewDormann the copy constructor seems to show everything properly copied, but the next time I try to retrieve the document object from the array, its member objects are empty.

Comment: @AndyProwl Heh, I had that problem separately before I made my own copy constructor, because this is part of a loop that was initially rewriting over the same pointer until I started `new`ing it in the loop and then in the copy constructor.

Comment: My money is on a double-delete due to violation of the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three): forgetting copy assignment.  Doing this without pointers would be simpler, faster, use less memory.

Comment: I have an explicit destructor as well, but no assignment operator.

Comment: Could we see the regular constructor?

Comment: You might want to add the class declaration to the post as well. I see a lot of code that I would write in a slightly different way but nothing that is obviously wrong.

Comment: @MooingDuck I think you're onto something.  I stepped back through the code and I think I was incorrect initially.  It looks like it isn't correctly populating the arrays in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that you've posted the full class definition, it is clear that you are indeed violating the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three): **If you need to explicitly declare either the destructor, copy constructor or copy assignment operator yourself, you probably need to explicitly declare all three of them.**

You have a copy constructor, and a destructor, but no copy assignemnt.  Add these members and you should be fine.

```
CMyDocument& operator=(CMyDocument cSourceDoc) {
    swap(cSourceDoc);
    return *this;
}

void swap(CMyDocument& cSourceDoc) {
   using std::swap;
   swap(m_lpacLines, cSourceDoc.m_lpacLines);
   swap(m_lpastrFields, cSourceDoc.m_lpastrFields);
   swap(m_strDocDate, cSourceDoc.m_strDocDate);
   swap(m_nDocID, cSourceDoc.m_nDocID);
   swap(m_strDocType, cSourceDoc.m_strDocType);
}
```

Your constructor allocates memory, and makes a member point at it.  Somewhere in your code you are making a copy of a `CMyDocument`.  Since you have no copy assignment operator, the compiler uselessly made one for you, that simply copies the pointer, so that you then have *two* `CMyDocument` objects pointing at the same `CArray` and `CStringArray`.  Then, when one of them is deleted, they delete the `CArray` and `CStringArray`, and the other `CMyDocument` is left with useless pointers that point at invalid memory.  When you are attempting to use that invalid memory, *sometimes, if you get lucky* you'll see what used to be there.  In this case, the empty `CArray` and `CStringArray`.  (They empty themselves right as they are deleted).  If you weren't lucky, the program would have simply crashed.

Comment: I'd also like to add that this could probably be solved by the *Rule of Zero*.

Comment: Yes, in another class I have an array of these document objects.  It calls the copy constructor whenever I add a document to the array.  I'll test this out in a couple hours.

Comment: Two problems: 1) I think that second `return this` in the swap function is incorrect, since it's a void function.  2) I'm getting the following error for the operator= function: `error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'CMyDocument *const ' to 'CMyDocument &'`

Comment: Well, I thought this was working, because it looked like it copied correctly, but it's still crashing later on when it tries to access the array.

Comment: Okay, I figured out the last problem. I needed to initialize the m_lpacLines object pointer to `NULL` to avoid an exception in the destructor.

Comment: @JoeMajsterski: Sorry I had the code not quite right, but I'm glad you figured it out!